# How to auto refresh a refreshable excel sheet using VBs

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Please share your thoughts on refreshing an excel sheet using VBs which is connected to oracle data base through ODAC.

my code as follow. Current issue is file is getting saved before refreshing the background query.

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

' Disable Excel UI elements
oExcel.Visible = False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False  


Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Excel\InitialRefreshableSheet.xlsx")
oWorkbook.RefreshAll

oWorkbook.WorkSheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Now()

DStr = FormatDateTime( Now, vbLongDate)

oWorkbook.Saveas ":\Excel\" & Dstr &".xlsx"
oWorkbook.Close
oExcel.Quit
```

Is there a way to tell a vbs script to pause until the refresh action is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following and it worked.

un-selected the Enable Background Refresh option from the external connection properties.

used 
    oWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").Refresh instead of RefreshAll.

Also used exception handling as well.

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'error handling:
WScript.Echo Err.Number & " Srce: " & Err.Source & " Desc: " &  Err.Description
Err.Clear
oWorkbook.Close
oExcel.Quit

Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
Else
 oWorkbook.Saveas "E:\excel\newexcel.xlsx"
 oWorkbook.Close
 oExcel.Quit   


 Set oWorkbook = Nothing
 Set oExcel = Nothing

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `oWorkbook.RefreshAll` I'd try refreshing synchronously by settting `QueryTable.BackgroundQuery` property to `False` for appropriate cell range(s):

```
For Each wks In oWorkbook.Worksheets
  wks.Range("Xy").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh _
                  BackgroundQuery = False
Next 'wks
```

or generally as follows:

```
For Each wks In oWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each qs In wks.QueryTables
        qs.Refresh BackgroundQuery = False
    Next 'qs
Next 'wks
```